# How to combine polygons in a vector with GRASS?

Tags: geoprocessing, grass-gis, vector

I need to combine polygons of similar geological classes which are stored in a vector file called geology.  I was looking for something like "union selected features" or similar. In the GRASS Book 3ed I found that v.overlay could be useful, however I did not manage to merge/union my classes.

To illustrate it, here an example: I have a polygon with class (column MAIN_LITHO) 'biotite granite' but also 'biotite granite (foliated) and others. These should be all combined into one single multipolygon 'biotite granite'. Later, I want to turn that vector into a raster map but that should be easy.

here is also an image of that example

[image]

Comment: Do you need the merged polygons for anything else but coverting them to raster?

Comment: At present there are 208 classes and I need something around 20 to have something to work with. I found the solution already. reclass would be the magic word. sadly I cannot answer yet my own questions, otherwise I could explain a bit more. What I needed wass either r.reclass or v.reclass. I found it after skimming again through the GRASS book. Sorry for my confusing terminology earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The combination of the polygons is fairly easy to obtain in three steps:

- add a new column (v.db.addcol), copy over the values from either the cat column or the textual column (v.db.update);
- Update the new column again with a selection of either the categories of interest or string selection (where="MAIN_LITHO LIKE 'biotite%'" ; requires a real SQL backend like SQLite or PostgreSQL) in order to obtain the same value for all biotite entries;
- Finally run v.dissolve on this new column.

Then you will have the task solved (there is no need to rasterize).

Answer (score 0):

You could select your polygons and then calculate a new field to use to dissolve on. Or, as underdark says, if you only need them to create the raster, just export your selection to a new file, and convert that to raster.